# reading file metadata using lua

Tags: lua, metadata

I wonder if there is a better code/library that would allow reading the file metadata?

So far, I have tried using `LuaFileSystem` and `LuaCom` (`Scripting.FileSystemObject`) but so far none was able to extract all the data. When I mean all the data, other than the usual standard data such as date accessed, date created, date modified, etc, I wanted some more data like in the case for pdf, it will contain other data such as author and title and for image, it will contain  data like bit depth, resolution.

Comment: where do you get that data from normally?

Comment: From pdf, html, doc, text. It will be good if I can get all file types such as image, video and ppt.

Comment: No, I mean what *tool* would you normally use to get that data from those files.

Comment: So far I have not used any tools to get the data out of the file. So if there is tools available to get that data out, what has it got to do with Lua?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be missing the difference between *filesystem* metadata and *document* metadata. Filesystem metadata is the metadata the filesystem stores about a file. *Every* file has this stuff, because every file is stored on the filesystem. This metadata is not actually stored *within* the file; if you loaded the file, that wouldn't give you access to the filesystem metadata. You have to talk to the filesystem to get it.

Document metadata is some bit of information *within the file* that serves as metadata. To get this data you have to read the file, know what the file's format is, and parse that metadata out.

I don't know of any library, Lua or otherwise, that is designed to extract arbitrary metadata from arbitrary file types.